# Rewrite url with #params to query params with nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I want to add a nginx rewrite rule which will change #params to query params.

> ex :  from https://x.app.com/callback#x=1 to
>   https://x.app.com/callback?x=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible - the part with # and after are never sent to the web server (per HTTP specification), only the client (web browser) has access to it.

The only way of using the # part is client-side javascript, unfortunately - that is why I would recommend not using it.